# Azure nodejs app not starting, invalid start-up command

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service

I have a nodejs typescript project cloned from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/typescript_nodejs/13.core-bot and when trying to deploy it to Azure I get the following error on logs:

```
Invalid start-up command "tsc --build && node ./lib/index.js" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

UPDATE:

```
{
"name": "core-bot",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A bot that demonstrates core AI capabilities",
"author": "Microsoft Bot Framework Team",
"license": "MIT",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json 'src/**/*.ts'",
    "postinstall": "npm run build && node ./deploymentScripts/webConfigPrep.js",
    "start": "tsc --build && node ./lib/index.js",
    "test": "tsc --build && nyc mocha lib/tests/**/*.test.js",
    "watch": "node --watch ./src -e ts --exec \"npm run start\""
},
"nyc": {
    "extension": [
        ".ts",
        ".tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "**/.eslintrc.js",
        "**/*.d.ts",
        "**/*.test.*",
        "**/tests",
        "**/coverage",
        "**/deploymentScripts",
        "**/src/index.ts"
    ],
    "reporter": [
        "text"
    ],
    "all": true
},
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/recognizers-text-data-types-timex-expression": "1.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "botbuilder": "~4.7.0",
    "botbuilder-ai": "~4.7.0",
    "botbuilder-dialogs": "~4.7.0",
    "botbuilder-testing": "~4.7.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "replace": "~1.1.1",
    "restify": "~8.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "6.1.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
    "@types/restify": "8.4.1",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "~3.6.4"
}
```

}

Comment: Not really sure why you get the error, but I would try updating the command to:
"node ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build && node ./lib/index.js" and give it a try

Comment: updated package.json as you said and now getting Start script "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build && node ./lib/index.js" from package.json is not found.

Comment: wait a second I am not mentioning anywhere about npm install in package.json when starting script

Comment: @KostasX didn work as u suggested!

Comment: Can you post the package.json script section?

Comment: updated my question, you can see how package.json looks like

Comment: Are you running this in PowerShell? Can you try from command line?

Comment: whenever I push to master, it trigger a deployemnt to azure!

Comment: Try changing `&&` to `;` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Any update for this issue?